# TFS separate branch from parent

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

In TFS we have a project P1. I have created a branch of P1. Now the branch needs to be separated from its parent and go on as a stand alone project P2. We don't need to keep the initial history for P2.

How can this separation be done?

Comment: You can Get Latest and then  create a new branch with the same name. Then just add your source code if history and such aren't important.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike, but that's not what I'm aiming at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source control window select the branch you want to 'orphan'.
Goto File > Source Control > Branching and Merging > Reparent...

[image: Select Reparent]

Then choose `No Parent` in the Dialogue and click `Reparent`

[image: Reparent Dialogue]

Comment: Thanks. It seems I don't have rights to reparent since it's missing from my context menu.